# Disciplined Vs. amenable in a specific context

Tags: word-in-context

What does more fit to a child listen and do what his parent asks for?

He's a good boy as well as **disciplined**.

He's a good boy as well as **amenable**.

Comment: If his parents *ask* him then he is amenable, but if they *tell* him he would be disciplined.

Comment: Thank you. How is more natural or common to describe a child by his parents?

Comment: We would normally describe a child as disciplined if the child, without being instructed, does unpleasant tasks such as chores or homework. An amenable child would do such tasks if asked, but might not initiate them.

Comment: _Disciplined_ sounds as though they are very strict parents who expect their child to to exactly as he is told. An _amenable_ child would do as he was asked because he loved his parents and wanted to please them.